# Sending a live location of the (telegram bot user) to other user using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, location, telegram, live, python-telegram-bot

Sending a **live location** of the (telegram bot user) to other user using python-telegram-bot.
How is it possible?
If live_location **won't** work, **how about using IP address of the user and then track user's location latitudes and longitudes?**